# Active Directory Recycle Bin and potential incompatibilities

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365

Having a Windows 2016 based domain (with domain and forest functional level at Windows 2012R2) I would like to enable the recycle bin feature.

However, I understand that this is an one-way change: once enabled, it can not be disabled. So, before doing that, I wonder if there are know incompatibilities and/or integration problems, especially considering that I plan to deploy AD Connect to synchronize our Office365 accounts.

From my understanding, it can be a live-saver [*especially* when using something as AD Connect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-recycle-bin). Moreover, based on what I read [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/776413/what-are-the-implications-of-enabling-the-recycle-bin-feature-in-active-director), the only drawback should be an increase in the DIT file. I am missing something?

Comment: I'm not aware of any incompatibilities or integration problems, as you say. I've got many clients with the AD Recycle Bin enabled who are using Azure AD Connect.

Comment: @joeqwerty Excellent! If you wrote an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any incompatibilities or integration problems, as you say. I've got many clients with the AD Recycle Bin enabled who are using Azure AD Connect.